# Images won't load for some reason

Tags: html

When you go to my page: http://daniell.nu/ you can see console errors, images I uploaded today won't load for some reason, they are in the same directory as any other image that you CAN see and they are called in the HTML the same way as the other ones that are visible, what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't see any console errors, there was probably just a small upload delay.

Comment: Check the file name (case sensitive) and also check the file permission.

Comment: I'm seeing `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
stap1.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
stap2.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
stap5.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
stap3.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
stap6.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)...`

Comment: When I click on the image it displays nothing but it does show images when I view them locally..

Answer (score 1):

## Your probem is your server is case-sensitive to your URL.

Note that `http://daniell.nu/images/stap16.png` 
is ***NOT*** the same as `http://daniell.nu/images/stap16.PNG` .

This is error 404: http://daniell.nu/images/stap16.png 
but this http://daniell.nu/images/stap16.PNG shows the image:

[image]

Comment: Well that is very weird, I just changed all to jpg to make sure it works, thank you anyway

Comment: jpg or png doesn't matter, what *does* matter is `JPG` or `jpg` or `Jpg`.

Comment: @Daniell you can tick the tick next to my answer, thanks `:-)`